# How to obtain UUID of dynamic linker? (/usr/lib/dyld)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to obtain the UUID of `/usr/lib/dyld` (dynamic linker) of an iOS device, but none of the methods I have tried seem to work. The dynamic linker image (MH_DYLINKER) is not even loaded in _dyld_get_image. I have attempted the following code:

```
- (NSString *) getDynamicLinkerUUID {
    const struct mach_header *dyldHeader = NULL;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < _dyld_image_count(); i++) {
      const struct mach_header *header = _dyld_get_image_header(i);
      if (header->filetype == MH_DYLINKER) {
        dyldHeader = header;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if (!dyldHeader)
        return @"Cannot found header: MH_DYLINKER";
    
    BOOL is64bit = dyldHeader->magic == MH_MAGIC_64 || dyldHeader->magic == MH_CIGAM_64;
    uintptr_t cursor = (uintptr_t)dyldHeader + (is64bit ? sizeof(struct mach_header_64) : sizeof(struct mach_header));
    const struct segment_command *segmentCommand = NULL;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < dyldHeader->ncmds; i++, cursor += segmentCommand->cmdsize) {
      segmentCommand = (struct segment_command *)cursor;
      if (segmentCommand->cmd == LC_UUID) {
        const struct uuid_command *uuidCommand = (const struct uuid_command *)segmentCommand;
        const uint8_t *uuid = uuidCommand->uuid;
        NSString* uuidString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                                 uuid[0], uuid[1], uuid[2], uuid[3],
                                 uuid[4], uuid[5], uuid[6], uuid[7],
                                 uuid[8], uuid[9], uuid[10], uuid[11],
                                 uuid[12], uuid[13], uuid[14], uuid[15]];
        NSLog(@"UUID: %@", uuidString);
        return [uuidString lowercaseString];
      }
    }
    return @"";
}
```

This always return "Cannot found header: MH_DYLINKER"

Please let me know how can I get it.

Answer (score 1):

As you already observed `_dyld_get_image_header(..)` will omit `/usr/lib/dyld` from the results. Your process does not have any easy way to access it through Apple APIs.

That's what `lldb` does:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-421.1/include/mach-o/dyld_process_info.h.auto.html

> When starting a process, lldb starts the process suspended, finds
> the "_dyld_debugger_notification" symbol in dyld, sets a break
> point on it, then resumes the process.  Dyld will call
> _dyld_debugger_notification() with a list of images that were just added or removed from the process.  Dyld calls this function before
> running any initializers in the image, so the debugger will have a
> chance to set break points in the image.

This is how lldb's

```
image list dyld
[  0] 651EB4D8-A0F0-3C97-A0C4-6A8F6FC17A56 0x00000001051c4000 /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.3 (17C54) arm64e/Symbols/usr/lib/dyld
```

works.

**Not so pretty hacks territory**

If your process uses `LC_MAIN` to launch (should be pretty much a guarantee on any modern iOS i.e. iOS11 and beyond) the `premain` (i.e. marked with C++ constructor attribute) function will return to dyld executable address space.

My previous approach (edited out) using regular `main` won't work below iOS15 because the main executable returns to libdyld.dylib instead of dyld.

Thankfully the `premain` approach works on all iOS versions I tested, which specifically are:
iPhone 11 iOS 13.3
iPhone 12 iOS 14.1
ipad 9th gen iOS 15.1
iPad mini 6th generation iOS 15.4.1
iPhone 13 Pro iOS 15.5
iPhone 7 iOS 15.7.5
iPhone 8 iOS 16.0

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain(void) {
    // find the return address of the premain function
    char *ptr = __builtin_extract_return_addr (__builtin_return_address (0));
    
    // search backwards in memory for dyld's Mach-o header
    while (*(int*)ptr != MH_MAGIC_64 && *(int*)ptr != MH_CIGAM_64) {
        ptr--;
    }

    const struct mach_header_64 *dyldHeader = (struct mach_header_64 *)ptr;

    BOOL is64bit = dyldHeader->magic == MH_MAGIC_64 || dyldHeader->magic == MH_CIGAM_64;
    uintptr_t cursor = (uintptr_t)dyldHeader + (is64bit ? sizeof(struct mach_header_64) : sizeof(struct mach_header));
    const struct segment_command *segmentCommand = NULL;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < dyldHeader->ncmds; i++, cursor += segmentCommand->cmdsize) {
      segmentCommand = (struct segment_command *)cursor;
      if (segmentCommand->cmd == LC_UUID) {
        const struct uuid_command *uuidCommand = (const struct uuid_command *)segmentCommand;
        const uint8_t *uuid = uuidCommand->uuid;
        NSString* uuidString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                                 uuid[0], uuid[1], uuid[2], uuid[3],
                                 uuid[4], uuid[5], uuid[6], uuid[7],
                                 uuid[8], uuid[9], uuid[10], uuid[11],
                                 uuid[12], uuid[13], uuid[14], uuid[15]];
        NSLog(@"UUID: %@", uuidString);
      }
    }
}
```

**Even more crazy hacks territory**
OP seems to observe a different launch for iOS13 & iOS14 devices when an aws device farm is used. The `premain` seems to return to libdyld.dyld .
Here's yet another hack for iOS13.x and iOS14.x

```
void searchBackwardsPrintUUID(char *ptr) {
    // search backwards for Mach-o header
    while (*(int*)ptr != MH_MAGIC_64 && *(int*)ptr != MH_CIGAM_64) {
        ptr--;
    }

    const struct mach_header_64 *dyldHeader = (struct mach_header_64 *)ptr;

    BOOL is64bit = dyldHeader->magic == MH_MAGIC_64 || dyldHeader->magic == MH_CIGAM_64;
    uintptr_t cursor = (uintptr_t)dyldHeader + (is64bit ? sizeof(struct mach_header_64) : sizeof(struct mach_header));
    const struct segment_command *segmentCommand = NULL;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < dyldHeader->ncmds; i++, cursor += segmentCommand->cmdsize) {
      segmentCommand = (struct segment_command *)cursor;
      if (segmentCommand->cmd == LC_UUID) {
        const struct uuid_command *uuidCommand = (const struct uuid_command *)segmentCommand;
        const uint8_t *uuid = uuidCommand->uuid;
          uuidString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                                 uuid[0], uuid[1], uuid[2], uuid[3],
                                 uuid[4], uuid[5], uuid[6], uuid[7],
                                 uuid[8], uuid[9], uuid[10], uuid[11],
                                 uuid[12], uuid[13], uuid[14], uuid[15]];
        NSLog(@"UUID: %@", uuidString);
      }
    }
}

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain() {
    unsigned char *ptr;
    register unsigned char* x0
#if defined(__arm64__)
    asm("x0");
    #if __IPHONE_14_0
        asm volatile (
            "ldr x0, [sp, #8] \r\n"
            :"=r"(x0)
        );
    #elif __IPHONE_13_0
        asm volatile (
            "ldr x0, [sp] \r\n"
            :"=r"(x0)
        );
    #endif

#endif
    if (@available(iOS 15, *)) {
        // find the return address of the premain function
        ptr = __builtin_extract_return_addr (__builtin_return_address (0));
    } else if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
        ptr = x0;
    } else { // iOS11
        // find the return address of the premain function
        ptr = __builtin_extract_return_addr (__builtin_return_address (0));
    }
     searchBackwardsPrintUUID(ptr);
}
```

Please provide debug logs of following code from the aws device farm:

```
static bool once = true;
static void image_added(const struct mach_header *mh, intptr_t slide) {

    if (once) {
        once = false;
        NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSThread.callStackSymbols];
        os_log_with_type(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, OS_LOG_TYPE_ERROR, "%@", string);
    }
}

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain(void) {
    char *ptr;
    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSThread.callStackSymbols];
    os_log_with_type(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, OS_LOG_TYPE_ERROR, "%@", string);
    _dyld_register_func_for_add_image(&image_added);
}
```

Comment: This does return a uuid but its not /usr/lib/dyld uuid. Please let me know how to return its uuid.

Comment: I am using several phones to test, the code you provided is giving me uuid of `/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib` not `/usr/lib/dyld`. I tested iPhone 8, 5s, 11 Pro, X with different iOS versions but none of them returned the correct one. Can you please double check? The `7C9C7851823738A7B1EB9CD2DEB4B746` is correct for 15.5 arm64e phone tho.

Comment: On iPhone12,1 (14.2) & iPhone12,3 (14.2, 14.3) it always returns uuid of /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib.

iPhone12,1 (14.2) id returned: BA60CB9E95C53646BEEDD313E15586CF
iPhone12,3 (14.2) id returned: BA60CB9E95C53646BEEDD313E15586CF
iPhone12,3 (14.3) id returned: 785BEE7FAC2C388D865C36279D1B3DD1

Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: - I ran it on iPhone 6s 14.7.1 as well and it returned uuid of /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib too.

Comment: Only iOS 14 devices i am testing are returnning /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib. I ran on one iPhone 12 ios 14.8 and it didnt return /usr/lib/dyld either.

Comment: On my own phones running versions lower than 15 does return correct uuid of dyld but when I run the ipa on real device farms, it doesn't. The premain function doesn't work in these devices? They are real devices tho.

Comment: I don't have access to that many physical iOS14.x . An iOS14.5 simulator yields same results as my physical iOS 14.2 so the `premain` works. I also tried launching without lldb (from an icon) and get the same results.  Also with a release build. Your device farm seems to have a specific way of launching the apps, but I don't have a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: I checked 3 different device farms with 30+ devices each. All of them gave uuid of /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib for iOS versions below 15. My real device with 14.x returns correct dyld uuid but device farms won't. Maybe the premain function is shifted to main? -- the devices on farms are loaded into cloud but act as real devices.

Comment: @Lucilfer at this point I'm blind coding against your farm setup but please check the new hack.

Comment: The app is crashing on my farm devices for iOS versions below 15. It works on iOS 15 & 16. I used x4 register.

Comment: The app crashed with the x20 register. With x21 register it didn't crash and returned a different uuid which is not even libdyld.dylib. Env: iPhone 11 iOS 14.0.1, the uuid it returned: 44E7E59A17333D2E90E3473269A3DAEA. On an iPhone 12 Pro running 14.4 it also returns the same uuid, looks like the x21 returns a constant uuid

Comment: -- on my real phone manually iPhone 11 pro 14.7.1 x21 returns correct dyld uuid.

Comment: I see. Without a way to reproduce the problem from your device farm, I'm really powerless to help.

Comment: I am using an external device farm. Its on a website and it will reproduce the same result. I am not sure how do I share the website with you? Can you try any iOS 14 device on aws? it will also give same result.

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to aws device farm. And I don't understand how them launching apps actually differs. Other than giving one last try with x19 I don't have anything else to recommend.

Comment: The x19 gives uuid BA11554B5E683A00A765CCFE296A796B. This is not the correct one either. Is there any other approach to get it? I rely on external device farms so I have no other way to do it. Would be grateful if you can find any other way.

Comment: On all versions on my real phones, the x21 register works but on all online device farms, it returns 44E7E59A17333D2E90E3473269A3DAEA. Do the cloud change the register for dyld maybe?

Comment: - UPDATE: The original premain function code you gave works on iOS 12, iOS 11 as well. It only gives uuid for libdyld.dylib in iOS 13 & 14 only.

Comment: @Lucilfer I've added an edit with more stuff to test. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Sad. Both the new methods crashes app on the iPhone 11 iOS 14 at the device farm but works on real phone

Comment: @Lucilfer try the new hack please.

Comment: Thanks. The app didn't crash but this time it gave uuid of /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib

Comment: @Lucilfer new day , new hack to try out.

Comment: This new hack also gave uuid of /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib :((

Comment: Is there no other way? Would be grateful if you could find a way.

Comment: @Lucilfer Can you use a debugger or at least print logs on this aws farm? Without that I essentially keep guessing. And the last result you provided to the best of my knowledge should technically not happen, so I'm really confused now. If we could run some diagnostic code on the farm and at least log stuff that could help finding a solution.

Comment: I recently moved from android to iOS 2 weeks ago so very less knowledge. Can you please add a log code in your answer and I will send these logs to an external URL. The farms don't let us use debugger, we just upload IPA and it works as a real phone.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but does the farm provide you a way to see the console or stdout output the device generates in the web page somehow?

Comment: @Lucilfer I've added a new hack, but I'm skeptical I can guess the solution without knowing what's going on.

Comment: Didn't have laptop with me for few days. I tried the new hacks but the app crashed sadly. The farms don't give console for the users so can't test it there.

Comment: @Lucilfer how can you inspect what's going on in the farm with your app? Do you see the app screen somehow there? Or in other words what can you do on the farm?

Comment: There is an inspect option named Console but it doesn't print NSLog there. I basically install the ipa and work on it.

Comment: So if your app running on the farm would display text or an alert would you see it somehow?

Comment: I've checked their docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/using-logging.html It's a little bit of a pain that it's dedicated for Swift. There is a wrapper https://github.com/srinikhil-07/swift-log-objc but that's extra setup

Comment: You can try `os_log` first https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code?language=objc . Maybe it will appear in the Amazon device farm console.

Comment: Like this `#import <os/log.h>
os_log_with_type(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, OS_LOG_TYPE_ERROR, "This is a debug message.");`

Comment: Nice, it just printed "This is a debug message" in the console after opening the app, i put this in the main function.

Comment: I've added code to print some stacktraces (at the bottom of my answer). Please edit & include the output in your question.

Comment: Its printing this only.
Jun 30 16:46:49 SHC[14579] <Error>: <private>
Jun 30 16:46:49 SHC[14579] <Error>: <private>
Jun 30 16:46:49 SHC[14579] <Error>: This is a debug message.

Comment: Ok, coming up with meaningful debug data will take some effort I'll think of something else. In the meantime I've edited the answer with new hack you can try.

Comment: The app crashed again with the new hack :((

Comment: Is there any other way? Really depending on you haha

Comment: New hack to test.

Comment: It returns a uuid but its not of dyld or dylib

Comment: Is there anyway I can identify in the device if its a device farm or a real device? Just a check would be okay, i collected 13-14 all dyld uuids, will return 32 0 zero if it uses a device farm and is on 13-14 ios version but for real devices can use the original method.

Comment: @Lucilfer try the new attempt